# Linux mint not detecting HDMI cable

Tags: multiple-monitors, linux-mint, hdmi

I am running linux mint 19.3 cinnamon with linux version 5.0.0-32. My machine is not detecting the monitor I have plugged in via KDMI cable. This monitor, cable, and port work fine when I run windows on my laptop, so it is not a problem with any of those.

The computer is an ASUS Tuf Gaming laptop with an nvidia graphics card. I have installed the recommended non-free nvidia driver.

When I try to connect my monitor, the display is not detected from my laptop, and the monitor gives me a 'no signal' error.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up needing to install a new driver. I installed form the nvidia driver page itself (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx). They have a search to help you figure out which driver you need.

Now my machine only sees the monitor and will not display on the laptop screen, but at least the hdmi connection is working